# Auto Refresh Without Effecting Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a auto chat section where I have to get the scrollbar of chat to the bottom. Like this:

```
function chatuser(user1) {
    $("#currentuser").load('chatcontent.php', {
        current: user1
    }, function afterchatuser() {
        $("#currentcontent").attr({
            scrollTop: $("#currentcontent").attr("scrollHeight")
        });
    });
}

<div id="currentuser"></div>
```

For the auto update I automatically refresh the function. Like this:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function chatauto() {
    chatuser(user1);
}, 2000);​
```

But every time it refreshes where ever the scrollbar is,it gets to the bottom. Like if the user scrolls to the top, after the refresh it automatically gets the scrollbar to the bottom. I want to stop this, but also it should get refreshed timely. Please help me.

Comment: To develop a chat, the best way is simply to use websocket. One project with chat example : http://easywebsocket.org/

Comment: problem wouldn't occur if you were only appending new data and not replacing all of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you basicly need is to change (increase) scrollTop of the messages container by the value of the new content height difference. Take a look at this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRVNr/) it should give you some idea.

```
$('div').scrollTop(function() {
    return scroll + $(text).appendTo($(this)).height();        
});
```

Here `scroll` old scrollTop value before new content appended.